# Is the generated topology translation-invariant?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-topology

I ran into the following exercise:

> Let H be a Hilbert space. Define $U(x,\epsilon),\ S$ as follows:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> U(x,\epsilon) &= \{y\in H: \lvert<x,y>\rvert<\epsilon \} \\
> S &= \{U(x,\epsilon ):x\in H,\epsilon>0\}
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> Prove that S is a subasis for the weak topology.

It's pretty easy to show that for every non-zero functional $\varphi\in H^*$, and every open ball $B(z,\epsilon)\subset \mathbb C $, there exists $x,y\in H$ such that:
$$
\varphi^{-1} (B)=x+U(y,\epsilon )$$

This reduces the problem to proving that the topology generated by S is translation invariant.

I've found that difficult. Can anyone provide me with a hint of some sort?

Comment: With the usual  definition of "subbasis" in general topology, this isn't translation-invariant. Every subbasic set, and therefore every nonempty open set, contains $0$. The author of the exercise probably meant that $S$ is a subbasis for the neighborhood filter of $0$, not for the  whole topology.